# Can I connect android through headphone jack to car stereo's USB?

Tags: usb, audio, music

Basically I want to be able to stream music (Youtube / Spotify) from my smartphone to my car stereo. Android outputs audio from its headphones female jack and my car stereo has a female USB port. Could I use something like this http://www.ebay.ie/itm/USB-2-0-to-3-5mm-Jack-Audio-Aux-Plug-Cord-Headphone-Earphone-Cable-male-To-male-/302373272893?hash=item4666d9fd3d:g:BFYAAOSwxH1UKaBm to connect both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely not, but it depends on the technical details of the components in question.  Most importantly, **Is the adapter simply a passthrough wiring change?  Or is it an active device that actually requires a USB host?**

---

### If it's a passthrough wiring change:

- Does the car stereo accept analog audio from the USB jack?

  - It *might*, by internally disconnecting the USB hardware and connecting some line-input hardware instead.  Or it might not.

---

### If it's an active device:

This is most likely the case because the description on eBay says it goes in a PC's USB jack, which I *know* is USB-only.

It probably announces itself as a USB soundcard, providing "speaker" and "microphone" capabilities to the PC.  In that case, there are two relevant questions:

1. Does the adapter have a "straight" pinout, or is it a "crossover"?

   - A straight pinout would be designed to plug into something that expects a phone on the other end, not into a phone itself.
   - A crossover would be designed to plug into a phone directly, but with the odd arrangement of a stereo mic/line-in and a mono speaker that is very quiet.  (basically a mirror-image of the phone's specs)
2. Does the car stereo even accept a USB soundcard?

   - Again, it *might*, but it may only accept a flash drive with audio files on it.

Technically, it might be possible to make a device that announces itself as a flash drive with one file on it and delivers a live stream as that file's "contents", in which case it might work with a flash-drive-only type of player.  But somehow that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: I guess I'll just buy it and test it out. Thanks.